# Sorting a list of objects using an object function

Tags: python, list, sorting, oop

I have a class players which have their name and experience as private attributes. I have 2 functions that returns each of them.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,name,experience):
        self.__name=name
        self.__experience=experience

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_experience(self):
        return self.__experience

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.__name + " " + str(self.__experience))
```

I created a game class that gets a list of players and it has a function that sorts the players based on their experience.

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, players_list):
        self.players_list=players_list
        
    def sort_players_based_on_exp(self):
        # I don't know how to sort them
```

I know that the sort() method has a parameter key, but I don't know how to use that in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The `sort` and `sorted` methods can take a callable of a single argument as a key function, and will sort on the results of it. So you need a callable that returns the attribute you want to sort on, given a `Player` instance. In this case, that's your accessor method.

```
def sort_players_based_on_exp(self):
    return sorted(self.players_list, key=Player.get_experience)
```

When sorting on an attribute, the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module has useful methods that are faster than a lambda to resolve an attribute key, but as noted in comments you don't need them here. See the ["Sorting HOW TO"](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) docs for some more examples and explanation.

As a side note - in general Python doesn't bother with obfuscating attributes and using getters and setters. The Python idiom would be to just have `experience` present as an attribute on the class. If you need to change the behavior later, you can replace bare attribute access by something functional with the `@property` decorator while maintaining the access syntax.

Comment: @KellyBundy. No only could but should. This answer is massive overkill

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper. That hasn't been the case since like python 2.5

Comment: Thank you, much better, and +1. Your last point is important: getters and setters are not idiomatic: properties are. `operator.attrgetter('experience')` would be the optimized search key here.

Comment: FWIW I still see the bound vs. unbound method distinction discussed in the 2.7.18 docs, but it's very much a moot point these days.

Comment: It's discussed because old style classes were still possible, but definitely not recommended. In new style classes (2.5+ if memory serves), and all classes in 3+, unbound methods don't exist, they're just plain function objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted(self.players_list, key = Player.get_experience)`. You can also define the order relations and then you won't need to explicitly give a key.

```
  def __eq__(self, other):
      return self.experience() == other.experience()

  def __ge__(self, other):
      return self.experience() >= other.experience()
```

etc.

The latter may be overkill in this particular instance, but I thought you should be aware of the option.

Comment: `sort`/`sorted` needs `__lt__` to be defined to work without a key

Comment: @Mark Tolonen [Oh really](https://tio.run/##ZYvBCsIwEETv@Yq9dQOlIPUggl7yGSJBbGIDJQ2bFSLit0drFAPOYQ4z74Ubj7PvN4FyPk@nGEFtBbwyGAtaO@9Ya4xmsi0kWa4ly9Il2EGq6MuPnXk0VPFk@Er@q@3L39UymUAf/d@zjcJ7kR@yESKQ84xxJjYDHhT2sgWFq3ev5VHKnJ8)? :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy Well, according to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list%20sort#list.sort) "This method sorts the list in place, using only < comparisons between items." but obviously `__gt__` works too.  but `__eq__` and `__ge__` as in this answer don't work.  The error message is even "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'C' and 'C'".  Sorry I didn't test every combination to see if the docs were lying 

Comment: @Mark Tolonen I think i once pointed that lie out to Tim, forgot what he replied. Anyway, the answer does say "etc.", so that would need to not include *two* of the remaining four order relations in order to not suffice. Though yes, I would've explicitly included `__lt__` as the first one.